# Best temperature storage IC? EEPROM or SRAM IC

Tags: pcb, integrated-circuit, temperature, storage

I am trying to integrate a temperature sensor along with the storage capability with it. Both temperature sensor and the storage device will be controlled by FPGA. Which device would be the most appropriate way to choose as storage device. EEPROM or SRAM IC or any other?

Comment: SRAM is a volatile memory so I wouldn't use it unless you are OK with losing data when power is removed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may be thinking of battery-backed static RAM. Such a thing does exist, and can be used as an alternative to EEPROM. EEPROM chips typically have a limited number of writes before they become read-only. That number is in the tens or hundreds of thousands per location, so that lifetime may not be a meaningful limitation, depending on your application. But if you must frequently log a value and must always be sure to get the most frequently logged value, and if that means that your EEPROM will have too short a lifespan, then you may have no choice but to use BBSRAM instead. The only limitation there is the amount of powered-off time your battery and chip combination will allow, and whether than exceeds your needs (if not, you will lose data).

Comment: Consider FRAM instead of EEPROM if you require essentially unlimited writes.

Answer (score 1):

SRAM is volatile RAM. It will lose its data when power is cut. EEPROMs are not. An EEPROM will keep stored data even when power is cut. Otherwise, SRAM typically has higher read and write counts, and comes in bigger sizes. So it depends on your needs.